# info api not showing git info with gradle-git-properties plugin in grails 4 app

Tags: grails, grails-4

I am trying to get git commit details as part of "/actuator/info" api end point using the gradle-git-properties plugin by following https://guides.grails.org/adding-commit-info/guide/index.html guide but having no luck with it. Steps I followed:

- "sdk install grails 4.0.8" //installing latest grails 4 version using sdkman
- "sdk use grails 4.0.8" //making sure my current shell is using latest version as well
- "grails create-app myapp --profile=rest-api" //creating a dummy app
- "cd myapp" //change working dir to the new app
- "git init" //initializing git
- As per the guide I updated the build.gradle

  ```
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
                maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
                classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.4"
                classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:2.0.2"
                classpath "gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:2.2.0"
            }
        }

        version "0.1"
        group "myapp"

        apply plugin:"eclipse"
        apply plugin:"idea"
        apply plugin:"war"
        apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
        apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
        apply plugin: "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"
  ```
- Also updated the application.yml file to enable actuator end points

  ```
        management:
            endpoints:
                enabled-by-default: true
  ```
- run the application using ./gradlew bootRun

I see that the git.properties file is correctly generated and placed under "build/resources/main" folder within the project folder.
But when I hit "http://localhost:8080/actuator/info" in browser, all I see is:

```
{"app":{"grailsVersion":"4.0.8","version":"0.1","name":"myapp"}}
```

But no git related info.
Raised the same issue here are well: https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/issues/161

Answer (score 1):

Solution has been provided by @virtualdogbert here : https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/issues/161#issuecomment-936544990

Basically we have to set path to the git.properties file for dev env:

```
environments {
    development{
        spring.info.git.location='file:build/resources/main/git.properties'
    }
}
```